# How do I override List<T>'s Add method in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, collections

I am currently looking to make my own collection, which would be just like a regular list, except that it would only hold 10 items. If an item was added when there were already 10 items in the list, then the first item would be removed before the new item was appended.

What I want to do is create a class that extends `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, and then modifies the `Add(T item)` method to include the functionality which removes the first item if necessary.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First, you can't override Add and still have polymorphism against [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), meaning that if you use the new keyword and your class is cast as a List, your new Add method won't be called.

Second, I suggest you look into the [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) class, as what you are trying to do is more of a queue than it is a list. The class is optimized for exactly what you want to do, but does not have any sort of a size limiter.

If you really want something to act like a List but work like a Queue with a maximum size, I suggest you implement [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) and keep an instance of a Queue to store your elements.

For example:

```
public class LimitedQueue<T> : IList<T>
{
  public int MaxSize {get; set;}
  private Queue<T> Items = new Queue<T>();
  public void Add(T item)
  {
    Items.Enqueue(item);
    if(Items.Count == MaxSize)
    {
       Items.Dequeue();
    }
  }
  // I'll let you do the rest
}
```

Comment: I agree, I think a queue is the best option in this scenario.

Comment: Keep in mind that my suggested code is in no way threadsafe. You'll have to do that yourself. :)

Comment: @Quentin: Indeed, I agree, sir.

Comment: "just like a regular list, except that it would only hold 10 items" sounds more like a Circular Buffer than a Queue to me.  See my answer.

Answer (score 77):

You can also implement the add method via

```
public new void Add(...)
```

in your derived class to hide the existing add and introduce your functionality.

Edit: Rough Outline...

```
class MyHappyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        if (Count > 9)
        {
            Remove(this[0]);
        }

        base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Just a note, figured it was implied but you must always reference your custom list by the actual type and never by the base type/interface as the hiding method is only available to your type and further derived types.

Comment: Apparently I downvoted this when I meant to upvote, just realizing it now, I can't change it :(

Answer (score 27):

You can't override Add(), it is not a virtual method.  Derive from IList instead and use a private Queue member for the implementation.

Answer (score 22):

You could extend [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) and override the InsertItem method to get the behaviour you want, and it also implements IList

Answer (score 10):

You can just write a class that implements `IList<T>` that holds an internal `List<T>` and write your own methods.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the best I can do is this:

```
class MostRecentList<T> : System.Collections.Generic.List<T> 
{
    private int capacity;

    public MostRecentList(int capacity) : base() 
    {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public new void Add(T item) 
    {
        if (base.Count == capacity)
        {
            base.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Since the `add()` method is not marked as `virtual`.

Comment: This is a very bad idea, your class no longer behaves correctly depending on the type of the variable used to send the Add message. *Really* you need to read up on LSP and the substitutability it describes

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use this method, your class will not work if it is cast as a List. Your new Add method will never get called. You really should consider using a queue.

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk what does LSP mean?

Answer (score 3):

Your description of your requirement sounds like a [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

I implemented my own - similar to [this implementation on CodePlex](http://circularbuffer.codeplex.com/releases/view/27751#DownloadId=69221) except that mine implements `IList<T>`.

Some of the other answers suggest using a `Queue<T>` - but this isn't quite the same thing, as it only allows FIFO access.

As a general point, it's not recommended to derive from `List<T>` - instead derive from `Collection<T>`, and implement any additional stuff you need.  But for a circular buffer it's probably more appropriate to use a private array rather than deriving from `Collection<T>` like the CodePlex implementation.

Comment: Collection doesn't allow me to override Add either.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the C5 collection library. They have an ArrayList<T> that implements IList<T> and have a virtual Add method. The C5 collection library is an awesome collection of lists, queues, stacks etc... You can find the C5 library here:

http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), your collection is a very poor candidate to extend List`<T>`, it is not even a great candidate to implement IList`<T>`.

What read patterns are required on this data? If you only need to look at all the current entries then implementing IEnumerable`<T>` and the Add(T) method should be sufficient to start with.

This can then be implemented by a private Queue (or Deque would be better but such a collection would require some other collections API and I do not suggest you try to implement one yourself) to which you Enqueue() during an Add (with Dequeue's if needed to maintain the size).

Note that implementing IEnumerable and providing the Add method means you can still use the Collection initialiser syntax if required.

If you need random access to the values then implementing an indexer may be a good idea but I don't see what benefit this would give you without more context on the question.

Answer (score 1):

It actually could be done, if Explicit Interface Implementation used.

```
public class SampleClass<T> : IList<T>
{
    ...
    void IList<T>.Add(T item) { ... }
    public int Add(T item) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Then called, like

```
IList<T> sample = new SampleClass();
int index = sample.Add(someStuffGoesHere); // new Add method is called
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extend `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`, which is much more flexible. You can then override the protected members `InsertItem` and `SetItem`, to customize the behaviour of your collection.