# Trimming entries in a List<string> after every write

Tags: c#, string, list

I'm doing repeated work on a `List<string>` to build an instance of `MyClass`, but for simplicity's sake (there are a lot of regular expressions and `IndexOf` operations involved), I have to currently Trim each line after every operation:

```
static MyClass Populate (\List<str> strList)
{
    MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();
    Operation1(ref strList, myClassInstance);
    TrimAllLines(strList);
    Operation2(ref strList, myClassInstance);
    TrimAllLines(strList);
    //...
    return myClassInstance;
}
```

Is there a good way (preferably a drop-in replacement ) to make it so that every time I write to `strList`, each string within is automatically trimmed?

Things I've toyed with:

- A wrapper of `string` that trims on implicit conversion. Would lose string Intellisense, and `IEnumerable`s do not similarly convert implicitly.
- Inheriting `List<string>` with indexer `get { return base[index]; } set { base[index] = value.Trim(); }`. The indexer is not overridable.

Comment: Why are you passing `strList` as `ref`? `List<string>` is already a reference type. Remember, `ref` refers to the *variable*, not to the *value*.

Comment: Eric Lippert: I know I don't have to; it's more of a reminder to myself that it's mutable, whereas strings are not.

Comment: That is a very poor programming practice. Only pass `ref` when you need to *modify a variable*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

`System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`

instead of your List

And do something like:

```
    ObservableCollection<string> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    void Init()
    {
        myCollection.CollectionChanged +=myCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void myCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        myCollection.CollectionChanged -= myCollection_CollectionChanged;
        //could be a delete / clear / remove at operation
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
            {
                string str = (string)e.NewItems[i];
                //the added value could be null
                if (str != null)
                {
                    string trimmed = str.Trim();                        
                    if (!trimmed.Equals(str))
                    {
                        myCollection[e.NewStartingIndex + i] = str.Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        myCollection.CollectionChanged += myCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }
```

after that, each time the ObservableCollection will be modified, the added items will be automatically trimmed.

Comment: Because of your `IndexOf()`, adding to the collection is now a O(n) operation. That could potentially slow down the code a lot.

Comment: @svick makes an excellent point; this slows down the collection a lot potentially. I note that you could make it faster by first checking to see if `str == str.Trim()`. If it does then there is no need to do the expensive search.

Comment: There's no need for the `IndexOf()` call: you can reference `args.NewStartingIndex` to get the index of the first item; subsequent items will be contiguous from there.

Answer (score 13):

> Is there a good way (preferably a drop-in replacement ) to make it so that every time I write to `strList`, each string within is automatically trimmed?

You don't want the behavior of `List<T>`, so *don't use `List<T>`*. Instead, make your method take `IList<T>` and provide an implementation of that interface that does what you want.

The implementation might simply be a wrapper class that contains a private `List<T>`.

See also this related question:

[How do I override List<T>'s Add method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580202/how-to-i-override-listts-add-method-in-c)