# Create list accepting classes that implement at least one interface C#

Tags: c#, list, oop, interface

I'm working on some project and I have situation where I need to create a list that would accept classes which implement at least one `interface`.
It should look like this:

```
interface A
{
    void foo();
}
interface B
{
    void bar();
}

class C : A, B
{
    public void foo()
    {
        // Do some stuff specific for A
    }
    public void bar()
    {
        // Do some other stuff for B
    }
}
class D : B
{
    public void bar()
    {
        // Do some actions for B
    }
}
class E : A
{
    public void foo()
    {
        // Do something specific for A
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<A+B> list = new List<A+B>();

        list.Add(new C());
        list.Add(new D());
        list.Add(new E());

        foreach (A a in list)
        {
            a.foo();
        }
        foreach (B b in list)
        {
            b.bar();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
`List<object>` doesn't really fits because I need to hold classes with interfaces **A** and **B** and execute specific logic for each `interface`.

Comment: `List<object>`? If you provide more specific details someone may suggest you a better approach.

Comment: How would this be useful? What could you do with each item in the list?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Indeed this sounds like a XY-problem.

Comment: Have you considered how this breaks Listkov?

Comment: Do A and B have anything in common? In that case create another interface `MeInterface` that A and B inherit from. Then construct List with type parameter `MeInterface`.
If A and B have nothing in common, using object as suggested by @Sinatr will do the exact same.

Comment: I would love some feedback re Sinatr's question.

Answer (score 1):

## Is a type implementing an interface?

To determine whether this is the case, you can use the [Type.GetInterfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterfaces?view=net-5.0) method. It returns a `Type[]` array of all the `interfaces` implemented by a type. Example taken from docs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nInterfaces implemented by Dictionary<int, string>:\r\n");

        foreach (Type tinterface in typeof(Dictionary<int, string>).GetInterfaces())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tinterface.ToString());
        }

        //Console.ReadLine()      // Uncomment this line for Visual Studio.
    }
}

/* This example produces output similar to the following:

Interfaces implemented by Dictionary<int, string>:

System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int32,System.String]]
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int32,System.String]]
System.Collection.IEnumerable
System.Collection.IDictionary
System.Collection.ICollection
System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable
System.Runtime.Serialization.IDeserializationCallback
 */
```

## How to get the type of an object:

```
myObject.GetType()
```

## How to create a `List` with objects implementing interfaces

You can derive the `Add` from `IList` and implement it, see [How do I override List<T>'s Add method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580202/how-do-i-override-listts-add-method-in-c) for example. In your case, you would need to check whether the type of the object implements an interface.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to guys in comments I created interface Base that is inherited both by A and B and used list with it